# Which is the latest API for the Watson Conversation Service

Tags: ibm-watson

I am checking out the documentation on IBM Cognitive Services and have come across two ways of connecting to my existing workspace.

[Version 1](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/develop-app.html#communicating-with-the-service)
[Version 2](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?node#messages)

My question is which of them is the one that needs to be used. They both appear to work but I am not sure which one to go with. Is there another API that is latest perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version API will be on the release notes and the API reference.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/release-notes.html

Using an earlier version number will disable later features, but any workspace created with a later version may not be backward compatible, and results may be unpredictable.

There is currently no way to create earlier workspace structures once there has been an update to the version. But if you have older workspaces, they will still remain compatible.